# I have 2 issues with the same bit of PHP with a pgsql query

Tags: php, html, postgresql

I am using drop down menu to create a user generate pgsql query. It works perfectly, however, I am now trying to convert it to work with multiple selections. I have run into 2 separate issues. When I add multiple to  it is no longer a drop down list, it behaves more like a scrolling wheel. As a note, the options are populated by an initial db query.

```
<select multiple name="userSite" class="form-dropdown validate[required]">
```

-While I am able to select multiple options, the query is only returning the first selected, rather than the results for all of the selected options.

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

$site= $_POST["userSite"];
$datea= $_POST["userDatea"];
$table= $_POST["userTable"];
$datez= $_POST["userDatez"];

// You need to do all of this if and only if this is a post request
// Also this method of detecting a post request is more consistent
if( !empty($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) && (strcasecmp($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'], 'post')===0)  ) {
    // Create connection
    $conn = pg_connect("host=xxxxxxxxxx port=xxxx dbname=db user=xxx password=mypassword");

    // Check connection
    if (!$conn) {
        echo "Did not connect.\n";
        exit;
    }

    $result = pg_query($conn,
        "SELECT *
        FROM 
        db.$table
        WHERE 
        $table.site_id = '$site' AND
        $table.created_on BETWEEN '$datea' AND '$datez' AND
        $table.soft_delete_id = '0';");

if (!$result) {
echo "Query failed.\n";
exit;
}
$num_fields = pg_num_fields($result);
$headers = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++) 
{
    $headers[] = pg_field_name($result , $i);
}

$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
if ($fp && $result)
{
        header('Content-Type: text/csv');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="customreport.csv"');
        header('Pragma: no-cache');
        header('Expires: 0');
        fputcsv($fp, $headers);

        while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)) 
        {
             fputcsv($fp, array_values($row));
        }
        die;

}
    exit('It works');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [humbolight](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1742249/humbolight) suggested, you need to set your name attribute to `name="userSite[]"`. But, that is only half the problem.  The other issue is with your database query.  You **can't** search for multiple sites with your query and it opens your code up to SQL injection.

Try this instead:

```
$site= $_POST["userSite"]; // this will be an array.
$datea= $_POST["userDatea"];
$datez= $_POST["userDatez"];
$table= $_POST["userTable"];

// verify that $table is a valid name since it can't be parameterized in the query.

if( $table !== 'my_table'
    || $table !== 'my_other_table' ){
    // exit due to possible sql injection.
    exit();
}

$params = array();
$params[] = $datea; // $1
$params[] = $datez; // $2

// generate the site query params
// we need a string like this: $3, $4, $5, etc. (one for each site selected)
$site_param_ids = array();
foreach($site as $s){
    $params[] = $s;
    $site_param_ids[] = '$' . count($params);
}
$site_param_ids = implode(', ', $site_param_ids);

$sql = "SELECT
            *
        FROM db.$table t
        WHERE t.soft_delete_id = '0'
            AND t.created_on BETWEEN $1 AND $2
            AND t.site_id in ($site_param_ids);";
//

$result = pg_query_params($conn, $sql, $params);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I understand what you are doing, but there seems to be a disconnect with "implode"... I set the name attribute with the [], but I am getting the following error when submitting the post...

Comment: implode() [function.implode]: Argument must be an array in /home2/rightme1/public_html/networks/gsreports/custom.php on line 24

Comment: Oops.  I fixed the missing parameter.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to add `[]` to the name attribute on your select element, in your example it would be `name="UserSite[]"`.  This allows multiple values to be encapsulated into one $_POST variable accessed as `$_POST['UserSite']` which will be an array of values, as opposed to a single value.